# Define macro as wrapper for parameters of a command

Tags: macros, context, parameters, definition

I'm trying to define a macro that is a little wrapper to a common parameter of a command. The macro is expanded, but the parameter is not taken into account by the command.

The macro, `\sp` is used inside an extreme table. Below are code and result: note that `\sp` is expanded, but the parameter is not used. **How can I define that macro to expand to an usable parameter?**

```
% define macro \sp
\define\sp{[bottomframe=off]}

% table setup
\setupxtable[frame=off, bottomframe=on]

\starttext

\startxtable
  \startxtablehead
    \startxrow
      \startxcell Head 1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell Head 2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody
    \startxrow
      \startxcell      A1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell \sp  A2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow
      \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell     \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablebody
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

[image: Result, with <code>\sp</code> expanded but not used as parameter]

Comment: As to explain why I reached at this: I'm writing documents in Markdown, and using Pandoc to generate PDF through a conversion to ConTeXt. Pandoc doesn't allow column or row spans on tables, so I'm figuring out how to fake that using borders. Turning bottom border off for a cell would make it seems as spanned. And using a macro for this is necessary in order to use default alignment of Pandoc tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a command takes a optional argument ConTeXt always checks if the next character after the command is `[` which isn’t the case in your example.

To pass the argument which is hidden in the `\sp` command to `\startxcell` you have make the `\sp` command expandable which can be done with `\defineexpandable`. The next step is to expand the content of `\sp` which can be done with `\expanded`.

```
\defineexpandable\sp{[bottomframe=off]}

\starttext

\startxtable
  \startxrow
    \startxcell Cell 1 \stopxcell
    \expanded{\startxcell \sp Cell 2 \stopxcell}
  \stopxrow
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

The better solution to pass the same arguments to a `xtable` multiple times is to create a named setup and pass the name as argument to the `\startxcell` command.

```
\setupxtable [sp] [bottomframe=off]

\starttext

\startxtable
  \startxrow
    \startxcell Cell 1 \stopxcell
    \startxcell [sp] Cell 2 \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5):

Imho there is no definition of \sp that will do it. You would need a variant of \startxcell that expands the following command once:

```
\define\sp{[bottomframe=off]}
\define\startxcello{\expandafter \startxcell }

% table setup
\setupxtable[frame=off, bottomframe=on]

\starttext

\startxtable
  \startxtablehead
    \startxrow
      \startxcell Head 1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell Head 2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody
    \startxrow
      \startxcell      A1 \stopxcell
       \startxcello \sp  A2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow
      \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell [bottomframe=off] B2    \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablebody
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

[image]